# Google Integration on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-api

I have integrated google login in my windows phone 8 app. Using Google [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#wp) Apis.

I am able to read profile info for Google Account.

I have not found info for Share/Post moment on wall,Invite People etc.

**My question is: Can we do this, If not WHEN?**

Issue : If its related to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41#c181), then where it written officially that Google is going/not going to support Write Stream Access.

Thanks,
Replies are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to post to someone's Google+ stream.

Google has not said anything official about Google+ API in ages. If you look at the issue site you posted you will see that people have been requesting this since 2011 and that there are currently 676 issues in the Google Plus issue tracker.

Reasons I personally think they haven't added it:

1. It may be they are not allowing posting because they don't want g+ to become like other social media platforms where you have bots posting.
2. It could also be so we are forced to use their APP to post.

Google+ is the most unloved Google API imo.

**Note**: you may loose this question because IMO its border line.

> primarily opinion-based  Many good questions generate some degree of
>   opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will
>   tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts,
>   references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Anyways its not opinion based its asking for possible things we can do so far

Comment: True its why I didn't flag it.  :)